# Angularjs - How to limit in ng repeat based on value

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using angularjs here my div will come based on onchange of drop down.Here I need to limit the h4 tag to only once based on its value.if suppose my value is critical coming multiple times it should be only once again if my value is major coming multiple times it should be only once like that.these values are coming from json so it is dynamic.Can anyone please help am new to angularjs,here is the code below

### html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select class="change" ng-model="x" ng-change="update()">
<option value="condition">condition</option>
</select>
<div class="main">
<div  ng-repeat="emp in groups" ng-attr-id="{{emp[attr]}}">
<h4 id="test" class="{{emp[attr]}}">{{emp[attr]}}</h4>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

### script

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.groups = [
    {
      name: 'Malaria',
      symptom:'fever',
      categoty:'critical',
      id:'1'
    },

    {
      name: 'cancer',
      symptom:'diesease',
      categoty:'critical',
      id:'3'
    },
    {
      name: 'fever',
      symptom:'diesease',
      categoty:'major',
      id:'3'
    },
    {
     name: 'Cold',
      symptom:'colds',
      categoty:'major',
      id:'2'
    }
    ]
  $scope.update = function() {     
   if($scope.x == 'condition'){
   $scope.id='categoty';
    $scope.attr = 'categoty';   
   }   
}
});
```

Comment: In that way it was not working so I asked different question

Answer (score 0):

You were a bit ambiguous when you say "is coming only once in the data". I think the behavior you are looking for in the shared plnkr is to allow the user to select an attribute and group by that attribute showing only the name property listed under the individual groupings.

To accomplish this, I built a selection of attributes the user can pick. So if a minor property is added to the objects in the future, it will continue to function and that can be added to the picker.

After picking an item, the data is parsed and it groups the items by the selected attribute. Each group is a key (selected attribute) mapping to an array (the item names). Once the grouping is made, two ng-repeats can display their data. The top level ng-repeat for each group category and the nested ng-repeat to show the items/names under the group.

```js
var jsonData = [
    {
      name: 'Malaria',
      symptom:'Fever',
      category:'Critical',
      id:'1'
    },

    {
      name: 'Cancer',
      symptom:'Diesease',
      category:'Critical',
      id:'3'
    },
    {
      name: 'Fever',
      symptom:'Diesease',
      category:'Major',
      id:'3'
    },
    {
     name: 'Cold',
      symptom:'Colds',
      category:'Major',
      id:'2'
    }
];

// Setup angular
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MainController', function MainController() {
    var self = this;
    
    // Setup your dropdown selections to choose an attribute
    self.attrs = [
      'category',
      'symptom'
    ];
    
    // On selection change, update how groups is built
    self.onSelect = function onSelect(attr) {
      // First build a map of all items grouped by attr
      var groupMap = {};
      jsonData.forEach(function group(item) {
        var attrVal = item[attr],
          arr = groupMap[attrVal];
        if (!arr) {
          arr = groupMap[attrVal] = [];
        }
        // Push the item name
        arr.push(item.name);
      });
      self.groups = groupMap;
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController as $ctrl">
  Select Attribute:
  <select ng-model="$ctrl.selectedAttr" ng-change="$ctrl.onSelect($ctrl.selectedAttr)">
    <option ng-repeat="attr in $ctrl.attrs">{{::attr}}</option>
  </select>
  
  <div ng-show="::$ctrl.selectedAttr">
    <div ng-repeat="(attr, names) in $ctrl.groups">
      <h4>{{::attr}}</h4>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="name in names">{{::name}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No it should not be like that,when you change the dropdown now critical is coming twice and major is also coming twice,but those should come only once.Each value should display only once. If in future I add 3 minor in category again minor should comes only once

Comment: you can see expected result and demo in this plunker,how it should be  exactly https://plnkr.co/edit/XEzYi1JEeOtvqC6xn9jZ?p=preview